# How to return unique column with the max version of another column in Linq to SQL?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I need return a query where all the unique page numbers are returned with the max version number of each page.

Here is the an example of the data that I'd query

```
DocumentID    PageNumber   Version
1             1            1
1             2            1
1             2            2
1             3            1
1             3            2
1             3            3
```

And here is what I would need to get returned in my query

```
DocumentID    PageNumber   Version
1             1            1
1             2            2
1             3            3
```

Not sure how to finish this:

```
var pages = from p in dc.Pages where p.DocumentID == 1 && ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
var results = 
    from p in dc.Pages
    where p.DocumentID == 1
    group p by p.PageNumber into g
    select new 
    {
        PageNumber = g.Key,
        MaxVersion = g.Max(x => x.Version)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This query may help you:

```
Select DocumentID ,Distinct PageNumber, max(version) from table 
group by DocumentID, Distinct PageNumber
```